# When the free upgrade to Windows 10 ends, can I re-enable Windows updates?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

As I understand it, the Windows 10 free upgrade ends July 29th. Back when GWX first became a thing, the solution was to hide the update, and disable Windows updates so it didn't install without your permission. Utilities like Never10 and GWX Control Panel weren't a thing yet. As such, I've been without Windows 7 updates for a while now.

Once the Windows 10 free upgrade is gone, can I re-enable Windows updates, without having to worry about GWX messages and the like? Will the GWX app be phased out of existence once the free upgrade period ends?

Comment: You really should keep your computer up to date despite GWX's annoyances. Microsoft also recently changed the GWX prompt to allow you to tell it to not remind you about the upgrade again. So you should be able to update your computer now and tell GWX that you don't want the upgrade.

Comment: I know, I wasn't comfortable with disabling Windows updates, but at the time it was the only way I could be sure I wasn't going to get an unwanted upgrade overnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to wait. Add the following to the registry to disable OS upgrades and turn off the GWX icon in the task bar.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]

"DisableOSUpgrade"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\GWX]

"DisableGWX"=dword:00000001
```

To add these, copy the text into a text file and save it. Rename the text file to have an extension of `reg`. For instance, I named mine `BlockWX.reg`. You can then run the file, confirm you want to make the change, and reboot.

**WARNING:** Always backup your registry prior to editing it.

You can then run Windows Updates without WX trying to install.

Comment: Cheers on the edit! It's a good habit to get in to. I'll try this out later tonight!

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not great with reg scripting, but Windows pops a dialog box telling me that the text inside is not a valid script. I also don't see either of the folders referenced within the registry, but I'm checking for updates to my machine now, and we'll see what happens.

Comment: I was able to update Windows 7 without selecting the KB update that includes the GWX app (i know it by heart from work...), and I avoided the Windows 10 upgrade download. I'll still mark this as the answer though, as it would work in any other case! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the confidence in my answer. I have used this on many PCs and know it will work. Sorry you had trouble with getting it to run.